# c++11 Makefile won't compile

Tags: c++11, makefile, g++-4.7

I have this simple Makefile that I used for my last program. In this current program however, I am using C++11 features, and can compile my program with `g++47 -std=c++0x test_list.cpp`, but when I use this in a Makefile, it brings tons of errors.

Files: `test_list.cpp`, `List.cpp`, `List.h`

Makefile:

```
proj2: test_list.o test_list.cpp List.h List.cpp
        g++47 -std=c++0x test_list.cpp -g -Wall -o proj2.x

clean:   
        rm -rf *o proj2
```

then I do: `make` and it compiles to tons of errors.

Comment: Since you have not shown the 'tons of errors', it is hard to know what's up.  It is surprising that you are not compiling `List.cpp` since you mention that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess given the amount of info you've provided.

```
proj2: test_list.o test_list.cpp List.h List.cpp 
    g++47 -std=c++0x test_list.cpp -g -Wall -o proj2.x
```

Are you missing the newline and tab at the start of the second line? (makefiles are whitespace sensitive).

Why not paste the list of errors you see.. that'll make it easier to help.

You've got no line to build the object file test_list.o either? (i.e. the proj2 target depends on test_list.o and also builds it).

Comment: Ya i have the newline, for some reason wouldn't do it in this editor. It gives me many errors, but this one is the main one: List.cpp:477: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x. Sorry about the bad editing, first post on SO...

Comment: How would I go about making a test_list.o...My programs due at midnight, help!!!!

Comment: First off.. test_list.o should be built automatically by make in order to get proj2 so I think you can remove it from your list of dependencies.  Second you're telling make that in order to build proj2 you need to build proj2.x  So change the -o proj2 (no .x).  

I doubt that will help.. but you seem to be seeing weirdness so it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Then I think you're going to have to post more info.  Try posting the first dozen or so lines of make errors.  Fix them from the top down.